# pandas dataframe converting boolean to varchar with read_json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file named 'file_data.json' that I read with Pandas.
Here is an example of the json data I have :

```
[{"data1":false, "data2":"hi"}]
```

I read this data with pandas

```py
df = pd.read_json('file_data.json')
```

the issue is when I display my dataframe it is converting `false` to `0.0` and `true` to `1.1`. How can I keep these values as booleans, rather than floats?

Comment: This error does not occur for me. It is correcly putting data1 as False when i run this code

Comment: Only thing is you have to change the code to df = pd.read_json('file_data.json')

Comment: have you tried with the parameter ```dtype={'data1': 'bool'}``` inside the ```read_json``` method? and if it doesn't work you can also try with [```replace```](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html): ```df['data1'].replace({0:False, 1:True})```

Comment: that 's works fine for me, dtype={'data1': 'bool'} , thank you